# What is this if condition doing: if (! --rank[x])?

Tags: c++

I don't understand this `if` condition:

```
if (! --rank[x])
```

`rank` is an `int` array, and `x` is an `int` variable.

I don't program in C++. My question is, why are variables in this `if` not of type `bool`? What is this about?

Comment: in what language(s) do you program?

Comment: What is unclear about this question? I don't understand the reason for closing it.

Answer (score 2):

> why are there variables in this if not of type bool

Convenience. When the C language was designed, it was descided that

```
if(variable != 0)    // same as  if(variable)
```

and

```
if(pointer != NULL)  // same as  if(pointer)
```

was so common that normal variables and pointers should be implicitly converted to *true* or *false* in boolean contexts. It was descided that `0` and `NULL` would be interpreted as `false` and all the rest `true`. They may have looked at earlier languages for inspiration to this implicit conversion.

This has saved programmers from millions of keystrokes.

C++ inherited this feature from C (as a lot of other things) and even though C++ has evolved a lot since then, this part remains.

Comment: And the lack of true `booleans` in the language has cost millions of keystrokes.

Comment: @user207421 Oh, how so?

Comment: This is a bit misleading. The C++ design was made to allow C code to compile, despite C not even having booleans (at the time). Now, the `if (std::cin >>i)` bit is unique to C++, but for the code in question you can't point to the C++ design.

Comment: @MSalters When I wrote it I was under the impression that I answered a C question so it was that design I was thinking of. When I woke up Today I noticed that it was a C++ question so I changed `NULL` to `nullptr` without thinking about the other part. I'll edit to try to make the connection clearer.

Comment: OK,so it was just checking if an array element is null. thanks guys, now everything makes sense :D

Comment: @very_secret_agent I have no upvotes left so, "you're welcome" will come this way. :) Yes, `!` (not) `<expression>` will be `true` if `<expression>` is `false` so if `--rank[x]` lands on `0`, then `! --rank[x]` will be `true`.

Comment: Back when C was developed people programmed on a teletype with output on a paper tape. The language allows for a lot of shortcuts because back then short was valuable.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `if (! --rank[x])` actually combines multiple aspects.

Before answering the question (what is the overall effect) I'll explain the aspects/elements that are being combined.

Firstly, everything there are a couple of properties of expressions in C++.

- all expressions may have both an effect and a result, and the two are not necessarily the same.
- The *result* of an expression allows an expression to be used as part of a larger expression (in the sense of more operations)

In your example, there is an expression using multiple operators, so it is an expression composed of multiple (sub-) expressions.

First there is the "array subscripting" operator - `[]`.    If `a` is an array and `i` is an integral value, the expression `a[i]` accesses the `i`th element of `array` (using zero-based indexing) and gives a result that is (practically, but over-simplifying a bit) a reference to that element.

So `rank[x]` obtains a reference to the `x`th value of an array named `rank`.

The pre-decrement operator has an effect of decrementing (subtracting `1` from) its operand and gives a result equal to the new value of that operand.   For example,  `--v` has the *effect* of subtracting `1` from `v` and gives a *result* equal to the new value of `v`.  That may seem to be splitting hairs, but the post-decrement operator works differently - it has the effect of subtracting `1` from `v` and a result equal to the *original* value of `v`.    So, the expression `foo = --v` has the same net effect as

```
--v;
foo = v;
```

whereas `foo = v--` has the same net effect as

```
foo = v;
 --v;
```

Although `--v` and `v--` have the same net effect (they both decrement `v`) the different result of each (new and old value of `v`, respectively) means that the value of `foo` is different from `foo = --v` and `foo = v--`.

The next part is the `!` (logical negation) operator.  For `bool` values, `!false` maps to `true` and `!true` maps to `false`.    For integral values, `0` is considered to be `false` and all non-zero values are considered `true`.   So, if `i` is an `int` then `!i` gives `true` if `i` is zero and `false` if `i` is non-zero.   If a `bool` is converted back to an `int`, `false` gives a result of zero, and `true` gives a result of `1`.

Now, to answer the question, we combine the parts above.

The construct

```
 if (!--rank[x]) something();
```

is equivalent to

```
  --rank[x];
  if (!rank[x]) something();
```

which, in turn, is equivalent (in net effect) to

```
  --rank[x];
  if (rank[x] == 0) something();
```

In other words, it decrements `rank[x]` and, if the result of decrementing is zero, the statement `something()` will be executed.

Generally speaking, expressing this as `if (!--rank[x])` is used by some programmers because it is more concise.    The down-side is, because it combines multiple effects, the expression is harder for a human to understand, therefore harder to get right.

It is also possible to combine a large number of (sub-) expressions into a larger expression, which therefore has multiple effects.    While more concise, the difficulty of understanding increases substantially as the number of sub-expressions increases.    Going overboard and combining a large number of sub-expressions into one is therefore inadvisable in practice - it is harder to get right, harder to debug, and harder (for anyone) to maintain.

Comment: Thanks man, now everything is clear to me

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, here is the standard language governing your example. The conversion of integers — or any other arithmetic type — to `bool` is one of the so-called *standard conversions* in C++.

The relevant section is 7.3. The chapter starts very generally:

> **7.3 Standard conversions [conv]**
> **7.3.1 General [conv.general]**
> Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning.

This means two things:

1. The compiler performs standard conversions for you automatically.
2. They are built in to the language (they are not a library feature, and not user defined).

Then there is a list of possible conversions. One item is

> (1.2) — Zero or one conversion from the following set: [...] and boolean conversions.

Boolean conversions are later defined as

> **7.3.15 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]**
> 1 A prvalue of **arithmetic [...] type** can be converted to a
> prvalue of type bool. A zero value [...] is converted to false;
> any other value is converted to true.

(A *prvalue* is simply a temporary.)

The standard also has a note:

> [Note 2 : Expressions with a given type will be implicitly converted to other types in several contexts:
> (2.1) — When used as operands of operators. The operator’s requirements for its operands dictate the destination
> type (7.6).
> [...]

This applies in your case: `operator!` is a built-in operator requiring a boolean argument.